# Why is C faster than C++ in code execution?

Tags: c++, c

Before I knew that C was faster than C++ I was able to write some simple code where C executed faster than C++'s speed.

So my question is: please explain then reason behind this.

If this has already been explained elsewhere on this site or the internet, please share a link.

Comment: Please define faster and provide some context.

Comment: This is *not a real question*

Comment: Its hard to comment on hypothetical situations. Post the test code.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/1618957/149482

Comment: http://shootout.alioth.debian.org/u64q/c.php

Comment: Unfortunately this question has been unjustifiably closed by the "We don't want our C++ language to look bad crew" when there are perfectly valid duplicates.

Answer (score 11):

The reason behind this is your poor test.

Comment: While this maybe true. The actual reason is more likely because of the probable simplicity of the test.
Please post the test code and let us see!

Comment: @MatiasFG, thanks for repeating what wilhelmtell just said.

Answer (score 1):

> C is not faster than C++ because C++
>   is a superset of C.

[Here](http://discuss.fogcreek.com/joelonsoftware/default.asp?cmd=show&ixPost=7461) it is!

Comment: C++ isn't a strict superset of C. Being a superset would imply that every valid C program would be a valid C++ program, and that isn't the case.

Comment: @Laurance I agree! I'll just say that C++ adds to some aspects of C.

Comment: Also doesn't some stuff valid in both languages have slightly different meaning in c++?